# How to pass numeric operator as a parameter?

Tags: c++, parameters, operator-keyword

In C++, we can do something like the following,

```
template <class OP>
int f(OP op){
   return op(1,2);
}

int main(){
    int res1 = f(std::plus<int>{});
    int res2 = f(std::multiplies<int>{});
}
```

How could I do the same thing with simple numeric operator,

```
int main(){
    int res1 = f(+);
    int res2 = f(*);
}
```

Exactly, what I want to know is how to write the line of 'return' in function f.

Comment: `#define f(op) []{ return 1 op 2; }()`

Comment: There's not many operators, so defining a wrapper for each is actually minimal code, and you could probably one-line the definitions if that really bothered you. It's probably better to leave this open instead, like just use `std::function` or a lambda as then you can have non-trivial ops, like multiply-add.

Comment: You can't. For class or enum types non-member operators would be feasible, and thus specifiable as an argument, but not for arithmetic native types. You seem to be askiing how to pass `T operator +(T,T)` as an argument, and the short of it is, you can't (what good would `std::plus` be if you *could* ?

Comment: @tadman • I reckon if you want to do OCaml, use OCaml, and not C++ trying to pretend to be OCaml.

Comment: @Eljay I mean more about `#define` which is kind of a dirty deed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How could I do the same thing with simple numeric operator,

You cannot; not using a function template. Operators are not something that can be passed as arguments or stored in objects.

> what I want to know is how to write the line of 'return' in function f.

There is no way you can write `f` as a function template that would make `f(+)` work because `f(+)` would be syntactically ill-formed.

As shown in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65623001/how-to-pass-numeric-operator-as-a-parameter/65623130#comment116024266_65623001), that can be done using a macro:

```
#define MY_MACRO_WITH_UNIQUE_NAME(op) \
[]{                                   \
    return 1 op 2;                    \
}()

int res1 = MY_MACRO_WITH_UNIQUE_NAME(+);
int res2 = MY_MACRO_WITH_UNIQUE_NAME(*);

#undef MY_MACRO_WITH_UNIQUE_NAME
```

Note that macros are prone to name collisions, so make sure that the name you pick isn't used nor is likely to be used by others.

There's no reason to do this rather than just using the template and `std::plus` that you wrote initially. Macros are useful though for defining a set of identical operator overloads for example, because in that case you cannot avoid using the operator symbol. Here is something that I've written:

```
#define FOO_DEFINE_OP(op, trait)                                     \
    template <class T, class = std::enable_if_t<trait<T>::value> >   \
    constexpr bool operator op(const foo<T>& lhs, const foo<T>& rhs) \
    {                                                                \
        return lhs.t op rhs.t;                                       \
    }

FOO_DEFINE_OP(==, boost::has_equal_to)
FOO_DEFINE_OP(!=, boost::has_not_equal_to)
FOO_DEFINE_OP(<,  boost::has_less)
FOO_DEFINE_OP(<=, boost::has_less_equal)
FOO_DEFINE_OP(>,  boost::has_greater)
FOO_DEFINE_OP(>=, boost::has_greater_equal)

#undef FOO_DEFINE_OP
```

This should hopefully become less needed with the introduction of defaulted comparison operators in C++20.